# How do I create multiple instances of an out of process RTD server?

Tags: com, singleton, multiple-instances, rtd

I have an RTD server that I created, and I want a different instance for each workbook as each workbook will use a different API key to access some data.  In other words, if I open Workbook1, and it uses Key#1, when I open Workbook2, I don't want it to use the same instance.

I know this probably has something to do with COM, and I have tried changing flags to "multiple instance", and I have tried modifying the singleton pattern, but the root problem seems to be that the instance that is created of the exe is the same.

Comment: When your server process calls `CoRegisterClassObject`, it should pass `REGCLS_SINGLEUSE`.

Comment: Thanks; I will try that next time I make a change; for now I have done a workaround.